# Legacy iMac screen extending

Tags: imac, screen, dvi

I'm looking to use an ancient (2008!) iMac as a screen extension for a 2019 MacBook Pro. The iMac is running with a pretty random collection of ports, including mini dvi. The Macbook only has USB C ports but I have a multi port dongle jobby. I've tried adaptors with the mini dvi to HDMI but just can't get anything to work.

Was wondering if anyone could advise how to get this to up and running!? Any cable recommendations!? Many thanks in advance!!

Ports on the iMac are below:

[image: weird ports!]